# set dirname to public_html/top directory?

Tags: php, joomla

how can i set to the top directory (i.e. `public_html/folder`)?

I have tried `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` without luck.

```
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(realpath(__FILE__)). '/folder' );
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the entire code in case it helps:

```
<?php

// Set flag that this is a parent file

define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(realpath(__FILE__)). '/folder' );

define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
jimport('joomla.application.component.helper');

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

if (!$mainframe->getCfg('offline'))
        {
    echo "Folder is <span style=\"color:green;\">online</span>.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?

Comment: try this define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );

Comment: i tried define('JPATH_BASE', dirname((FILE)). '/folder' ); but it hasn't worked

Comment: of course it didn't. it is __FILE__ (starts with 2 underscores, ends with 2) NOT FILE.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` works. your are doing something wrong.

Comment: apologies, i may have been unclear. i need to set it to public_html/folder

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for DOCUMENT_ROOT I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <?php
function getPublicHTML(){
    $get = 'public_html';
    $d = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++){
        if(file_exists($d.$get)){
            return $d;
        }else{
            $d.="../";
        }
    }
    return $d;
}

define("JPATH_BASE", getPublicHTML());
?>
```

Works under Wamp Server

Comment: unfortunately, i can't echo it. it has to be defined.